# How do I jump between sections of code like John Lindquist in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

**Question:** What are the commands I must press to navigate through a file in webstorm without using a mouse like John Lindquist does so often?

[Jump to 52 seconds](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-useful-behaviors) or look at this image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **AceJump** plugin in action. Install it via `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Plugins | Browse repositories...`

Plugin page: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086?pr=webStorm